# having trouble finding the inverse.

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{4}x^3 + x -1$ What is the value of $f^{-1}(x)$ when $x=3$?

First, check to make sure the fuction is stricly monotonic.

$f^{\prime}(x) = \frac{3}{4}x^2 + 1$

$f^{\prime \prime}(x) = \frac{3}{2}x$ Which is a linear function thus $f(x)$ is strictly monotic

Now, this is where I am having troubles finding the inverse.  I plugged the formula into wolfram alpha, but the result was not understood by me, thus, I don't understand how the result came about.

I have tried the switch $x$ and $y$, but that is not very helpful.

$y = (1/4)x^3 + x -1$

$y +1 = (1/4)x^3 +x$

$y + 1 -x  = (1/4)x^3$

$\sqrt[3]{4(y + 1 - x)} = x$

switch $x$ and $y$, then solve for y

$\sqrt[3]{4(x+1 - y)} = y$

$4(x+1-y) = y^3$

$x + 1 = \frac{y^3}{4} +y$

$x = \frac{y^3}{4} + y - 1$    IS THIS CORRECT?

$3 =\frac{y^3}{4} + y -1$

$4 = (1/4)y^3 + y$

$0 = (1/4)y^3 + y -4$

I have found [equation to solve cubic polynomials](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/)

I think that is a bit much.

There has to be a better way, is there?

Comment: Hint: Don't try to find $f^{-1}$, rather, try to find what value of $x$ makes $f(x) = 3$.

Comment: you mean $16 = x^3 + 4x \Rightarrow 16 = x(x^2 + 4)$,which I can only find $x =2 $

Comment: and that's your answer... :)

Comment: Its a third degree polynomial, how to find the other two roots?

Comment: The other two are complex.  You can perform polynomial division to factor out $x-2$ from the polynomial $x^3 + 4x -16$.  The resulting quadratic can be factored using the quadratic formula.

Comment: $f(a)=3$.  I recommend trial-and-error before doing much more work.  Evaluate $f(a)$ for some even integers $a$ (odd ones will give you fractional output).

Comment: Your statement about $f''$ being a linear function is meaningless! $f(x)=x^3/4-x-1$ also has $f''$ linear and it is not monotonic. Instead, note that $f'(x)=x^2 * 3/4+1$ is always greater than zero for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. That said, as $f^{-1}$ can be defined using sets regardless of whether or not $f^{-1}$ is a function or not, it doesn't really matter much. (the question would be, "what is _a_ value of $f^{-1}(x)$ when $x=3$".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f^{-1}(3) = a$.  Then, $3 = f(a)$.

So, this problem simplifies to solving the equation:
$$\frac{1}{4}a^3 + a -1 = 3$$

Rearranging:
$$\frac{1}{4}a^3 + a - 4 = 0$$
$$a^3 + 4a - 16 = 0$$

This is a polynomial with rational coefficients.  The only possible (rational) roots are $\pm1, \pm2, \pm4, \pm8, \pm16$.  With this, it is probably easiest to plug each one in, and see which is a root.

We can easily see that $a=2$ is a root to that equation.  As $a$ is the value we seek, we have our answer.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the previous answer, you don't need to find the inverse function as an explicit formula since you are asked to compute a specific value. Then, you'd get exactly what it's being said above. If you have trouble factoring the polynomial, just plug it into an equation solve online or your graphic calculator ("solve" or "factor" can both do the trick).
Hope this helps :)

Comment: I agree with you, just feel like I learn it better without the calculator when dealing with how to manipulate and use functions.  I only like to graph with my calculator.